# Is it possible to display component's shadow above an other component in the same View with using map function ? React Native

Tags: react-native

I’m creating a menu with React Native and it’s 3 components one below the others. I want to add shadows on the bottom of each component to add a little bit of perspective.
I want to create 3 buttons one below the others and I want to add shadow to create perspective.

My issue is that because of the map  function, all of my components are in the same View.
I want to find a way to add shadow without having a View into another (I find it quite messy).

I tried:
`position: "absolute"`.

but it doesn’t really work as my components pile up on each other instead of being below one another.

If anyone can help me it would be a pleasure.

Here is my code

Menu.js:

```
import React from "react"
import {View, StyleSheet} from "react-native"
import {StatusBar} from 'expo-status-bar';
import { useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native";
import Button from "../components/Menu/Button";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

const SCREENS = [
    {
        id: "play",
        name: "Play",
        color: "#F77F00",
        image: "",
    },
    {
        id: "cards",
        name: "Cards",
        color: "#FCBF49",
        image: ""
    },
    {
        id: "settings",
        name: "Settings",
        color: "#003049",
        image: ""
    }
]

const Menu = () => {
    const {navigate} = useNavigation();
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                SCREENS.map(screen => (
                    <Button
                        key={screen.id}
                        label={screen.name}
                        color={screen.color}
                        image={screen.image}
                        onPress={() => navigate(screen.id)}/>
                ))
            }
        </View>
    )
}

export default Menu;
```

Button.js:

```
import React from "react"
import {TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions, Text} from "react-native";

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: width,
        height: height / 4,
        shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 10},
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    text: {
        color: "white",
        fontSize: 64,
        shadowOffset: {height: 5},
        shadowOpacity: 0.5
    }
})

const Button = ({label, color, onPress}) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: color}]} onPress={onPress}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{label}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default Button;
```

[Here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfg9x.png) (haven't the possibility to embed image).

[And this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYIhG.png)